# Complete in $L^1$ but not $\mathrm{sup}$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

While learning a bit of functional analysis from an introductory book I got stumped by the following problem:

Find a linear space complete in the $L^1$ norm, $||f||_1 \equiv \int_0^1 |f(t)|\ \mathrm{d}t$, but not in the supremum norm.

I'm having trouble translating $L^1$ convergence to a useful property, unlike its supremum counterpart which gives uniform convergence. Thanks for any hints!

Comment: On $[0,1]$ no such space of functions exists. You can show this using the fact that the sup norm is strictly greater than the $L^1$ norm. So if $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in sup norm, it is Cauchy in $L^1$ norm, and so there exists $f$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$. But, since the sup norm is complete on the bounded functions, $f_n \to g$ in sup norm for some $g$. Since these limits agree when they both exist, $f = g$.